# observe property about the AVPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, iphone

my app is using AVPlayerLayer to show the AVPictureInPictureController, and i am using KVO to observe property about the AVPlayerLayer. `pictureInPictureControllerDidStopPictureInPicture`, in this method I remove the `playerView` and in the `dealloc` I remove the observer

When I stop the `PictureInPicture` and return to the live room, it crashes; console log :

```
0 QuartzCore!CA::Layer::~Layer() + 0xfc
1 QuartzCore!CA::Layer::~Layer() + 0xc8
2 QuartzCore!-[CALayer dealloc] + 0x48
3 AVFoundation!-[AVPlayerLayer dealloc] + 0x280
4 Foundation!NSKVODeallocate + 0x58
5 QuartzCore!CA::Layer::free_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 0xb0
6 QuartzCore!CA::Transaction::commit() + 0x27c
7 QuartzCore!CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 0x74
8 CoreFoundation!__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 0x1c
9 CoreFoundation!__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 0x170

0 libsystem_platform.dylib!_os_unfair_lock_unowned_abort + 0x24
1 libsystem_platform.dylib!_os_unfair_lock_unlock_slow + 0x78
2 libsystem_malloc.dylib!free_tiny_botch + 0x5c
3 QuartzCore!-[CALayer dealloc] + 0x54
4 AVFoundation!-[AVPlayerLayer dealloc] + 0x280
5 Foundation!NSKVODeallocate + 0x58
6 QuartzCore!CA::Layer::free_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 0xb0
7 QuartzCore!CA::Transaction::commit() + 0x27c
8 QuartzCore!CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 0x74
9 CoreFoundation!__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 0x1c
```

the method i add KVO

```
- (void)addObserverToPlayerItem:(AVPlayerItem *)playerItem
{  
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];

[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"presentationSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
}
- (void)addObserverToPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player
{
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
}
```

in this method i change the item and add KVO pictureInPictureControllerDidStartPictureInPicture:

in this method i remove the view 
pictureInPictureControllerDidStopPictureInPicture:

and when the view is dealloc i remove the KVO

```
- (void)removeObserverFromPlayerItem:(AVPlayerItem *)playerItem
{
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"presentationSize" context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
}

- (void)removeObserverToPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player
{
    [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" context:@"PIPViewControllerClass"];
}
```

Comment: when i stop the PictureInPicture and return to the live room, it crash

Comment: You've likely incorrectly handled KVO. You'll need to provide the code you're using to observe and to stop observing (and precisely where these are called).

Comment: i have changed the question with more details

Comment: When do you call these methods? A key point is that they  must be exactly balanced. You must call `removeObserver` on an object/keypath exactly as often if you call `addObserver` on the same combination. KVO also does not promise thread safety. You must be careful about an object being destroyed on one thread while an observation is firing on another thread.